# Recording Video in iPhone using AVFoundation Framework(AVCaptureSession)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation

i am developing an application in which i am trying to record a video using AVCaptureSession class...i came across a few good tutorials like this one

> http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/2-ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera

but in these tutorials only capturing images from the video frames is done while i want to record a full length video which i can either save in my device or upload it to my server....How can i achieve this using AVFoundation framework??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the sample code from the WWDC 2010 http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ for example the AVCamDemo.

Login to your iPhone developer account (the box with "Download WWDC 2010 Session Videos for Free") then you see a new page and there you can click on "View in iTunes" and then in iTunes(!) you get the link to the WWDC 2010 example source code... or you can try the link

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

but to download the source code you must also login to your developer account.