# iPhone video recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-capture

I have to record the video in iPhone by invoking camera programmatically. So kindly  tell me how to record the video using Objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Recording Video in iPhone using AVFoundation Framework(AVCaptureSession)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862402/recording-video-in-iphone-using-avfoundation-frameworkavcapturesession)

Similar question. You can control the camera device programmatically using the `AVFoundation` framework, and more specifically, `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

[This link](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera) might also help, there is a link to some source code using `AVCaptureSession` on that page too.