# Can someone point me to some AVFoundation Sample source code?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

Simple question but can someone point me to some AVFoundation Sample source code?

Answer (score 3):

See the blog post.

http://iphonedevtips.blogspot.com/2009/01/avfoundation-and-audio.html

http://www.oogtech.org/content/tag/avfoundation/

SO post.

[Recording Video in iPhone using AVFoundation Framework(AVCaptureSession)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862402/recording-video-in-iphone-using-avfoundation-frameworkavcapturesession)

Forum post

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15991-sample-code-avaudioplayer.html

Tutorial :

http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/introductino-to-av-foundation

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to implement a pause feature in AVFoundation?