# Capture front video Xcode 4 whithout UIImagePickerController (auto)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, camera

I want to capture video in my app without using UIImagePickerController. my application should record the video with a hidden camera front, and only after showing the recording.

I am new to me please help me with the programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use AVFoundation for what you want, check out this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862402/recording-video-in-iphone-using-avfoundation-frameworkavcapturesession)
 for more information on the matter.