# How to show the current camera capture in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I've got a small UIView, in which I would like to show the current camera capture. Also, I would like to use that data to do some analysis on the iPhone.
How can I display what the camera is capturing right now, and how to get this data?
Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend ;) [AVFoundation Docu](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) [Capturing tutorial](http://de.slideshare.net/invalidname/capturing-stills-sounds-and-scenes-with-av-foundation) [Duplicate SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862402/recording-video-in-iphone-using-avfoundation-frameworkavcapturesession)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recording Video in iPhone using AVFoundation Framework(AVCaptureSession)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862402/recording-video-in-iphone-using-avfoundation-frameworkavcapturesession)